# Using the word "haphazard"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Using the adjective **haphazard** you mean "lacking order or purpose; **not planned**". I need to know if the bold sentence blow makes sense in a natural way within my self-made scenario:

> After graduation in pure mathematics I decided to continue my education in French literature. Now, I have a master's degree in math and another master's degree in literature. But when I turn back and look at my past years, I think I have made a big mistake. As a successful businessman today, I think **all my studies have been [haphazard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haphazard)** (meaning not measured and calculated and without planning) **so far** while it was much better if I studied in the field of business management for instance.

If not, then please let me know what would you use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you used the word "haphazard" correctly, however there are a few other grammatical errors in your paragraph. I would suggest something like this:

> After graduating with a degree in pure mathematics I decided to continue my education by studying French literature. Now, I have a master's degree in math and another master's degree in literature. But when I turn back and look at my past years, I think I have made a big mistake. As a successful businessman today, I think all my studies have been haphazard, it would have been much better if I had restricted my studies to business management.

Comment: Just one more question! "After" always succeeds by a noun. While the verb "graduate" has the noun "graduation", why have you used the gerund form within your context?

Comment: You could say "After graduation, I decided to ..." but adding the clause "with a degree" changes things.  "After" is frequently followed by an action (present tense verb) so I don't agree with your rule.

Comment: "After" is frequently followed by an action (with a present tense verb) that functions as a noun phrase like "graduating with a degree in pure mathematics."

Comment: +1 for the reply @Ron Jensen. So would it be possible to say: "After **graduation** with a degree in pure mathematics I decided to continue..."?

Comment: *Graduation* is a noun and does not agree with *with a degree in pure mathematics* which is an adverbial phrase.